# Error executing a query involving MD5() function through Simba's JDBC driver

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery, dbeaver, simba

When I do a query through Simba's JDBC Driver 4.2 1.2.1.1001 version using MD5 function e.g:

```
SELECT md5('Hello World') AS hash_value from testdataset.table_sample
```

I get the following error trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQResultSet.getDataOldAPI(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQResultSet.getData(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SForwardResultSet.getData(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SForwardResultSet.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCResultSetImpl.getObject(JDBCResultSetImpl.java:613)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.data.handlers.JDBCContentValueHandler.fetchColumnValue(JDBCContentValueHandler.java:76)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.data.handlers.JDBCContentValueHandler.fetchColumnValue(JDBCContentValueHandler.java:1)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.data.handlers.JDBCAbstractValueHandler.fetchValueObject(JDBCAbstractValueHandler.java:49)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetDataReceiver.fetchRow(ResultSetDataReceiver.java:123)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.fetchQueryData(SQLQueryJob.java:686)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:499)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$0(SQLQueryJob.java:419)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:152)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:411)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:781)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsContainer.readData(SQLEditor.java:2852)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:99)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:152)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:97)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$17.run(ResultSetViewer.java:3431)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

I tried with different clients but got the same result.

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: I am using Java 8

Comment: Java 8 includes `javax.xml.bind.DataTypeConverter`, so that is unlikely, unless there is a classloader involved that doesn't allow your program to see it. In any case, given you're using DBeaver, you may want to ask on a DBeaver support forum.